# Fetch imageview to all the screen in relativelayout between buttons and edittext

Tags: android

I have the below XML relativelayout... I need help to make the image always fetch to all the screen but between above name ju and below buttons.

the following ImageView parameter make the image centered.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <   RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

   <TextView android:id="@+id/nameview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#FFFFE0"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingTop="14dp"
       android:paddingLeft="45dp"
       android:fontFamily="Arial"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:text="Ju" />


 <ImageView android:id="@+id/SingleView" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/nameview"/>

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/funnyBtn"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SingleView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/smileclk"
        android:background="@drawable/smileclk"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SingleView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/funnyBtn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="test1" />

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/test2Btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SingleView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="test2" />

   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test2Btn"
    android:background="#ff00ff00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:padding="10dip" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calculation" />
                <View 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"       
          android:background="#ffffff" />


            </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my result for now [image]

this is my desire output

[image]

Comment: You are not clear. Can you show us what is the expected output ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain in the image I have posted I want the river/tree picture to be in all the screen , now its looking centerd .. I dont  the gray on its side .. I want all the picture be fetched on the screen .. got me now ?

Comment: put this in your ImageView `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As murtaza mentioned adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"`  helped

```
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/SingleView" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:layout_below="@id/nameview"/>
```